# Como mudar o formato de uma célula com Pyhton e OpenPyXL?

Tags: python, microsoft-excel

Tudo bem com vocês?

Estou trabalhando com a transposição de bases de dados de um arquivo de Excel para o outro, e ao transpassar os valores para um outro arquivo, eu gostaria de setar os tipos de valores das células.

Como no exemplo abaixo, gostaria que a celula 1 fosse do tipo numérico, e as demais fossem texto.

```
'''
     Loop que percorre as celulas do arquivo armazenado em "bc" e cola nas 
     células do arquivo "da".

     Este loop verifica se o valor da terceira coluna é igual a variável "mall" 
     e a partir daí começa a fazer a transposição de dados entre os arquivos, colando os dados sempre após a última linha preenchida do arquivo.

'''

da_act = da_mr
# Realiza a transposição dos dados
for r in range(1, (bc_mr + 1)):
    if bc_ws.cell(row=r, column=3).value == mall:
        val = ''
        for c in range(1, (bc_mc + 1)):
            val = bc_ws.cell(row=r, column=c).value
            if c in [1]:
                da_ws.cell(row=da_act, column=c, value=val)
                da_ws.cell(row=da_act, column=c).TYPE_NUMERIC
            else:
                da_ws.cell(row=da_act, column=c, value=val)
                da_ws.cell(row=da_act, column=c).TYPE_STRING

    if bc_ws.cell(row=r, column=3).value == mall:
        da_act = da_act+1
        print(da_act)
```

Porém todas as células continuam sendo "Geral", e desta forma o Excel não consegue fazer calculos com os números existentes.

Como resolver? Lembrando que vai ter coluna que o número é sem decimal, e outras possuirão.

Comment: O que são `bc_mr`, `bc_mc` e `bc_ws`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom dia, Vitor.

Os formatos do Excel não são como os tipos nas linguagens de programação, eles são como uma regra e o Excel possui algumas predefinidas e da nomes a elas por exemplo 'Contabil', 'Texto' e 'Numero'. Nesta biblioteca do Python é possível definir esses formatos através da propriedade number_format das células.
Observe o seguinte exemplo:

```
# para que o formato seja numeros sem decimal
sheet['A1'] = 12
sheet['A1'].number_format = '0'

# para que o formato seja numeros com casas decimais
sheet['A2'] = 13
sheet['A2'].number_format = '0.00'

# para que o formato seja texto
sheet['A3'] = 'ASDA'
sheet['A3'].number_format = '@'
```

Qualquer duvida estou a disposição.

Caso queira entender mais sobre os formatos essa doc me ajudou bastante:
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/styles/numbers.html

Comment: Fernando,
Sua resposta me foi muito útil!

Consegui chegar a solução com o seu exemplo!
Muito obrigado!